# Understanding this line of jQuery

Tags: jquery

Line 3906 of jQuery 1.7rc1 is

`expando = "sizcache" + (Math.random() + '').replace('.', ''),`

I don't understand the point of using `+ ''`. Isn't the above equivalent to

`expando = ("sizcache" + Math.random()).replace('.', ''),`

Comment: yeah, you cant do replace on a number

Comment: The original jQuery way is, in theory, faster. String replace performance is pretty much tied directly to the length of the input string. Adding to the string length of the input with data you know does not need replacing is a direct, but small, performance loss. If this line of codes gets called a significant amount that performance savings might become noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're right. Just another way of doing it.

Comment: what if "sizcache" is a dynamic string that may have meaningful decimal points in it? :P

Answer (score 6):

`+ ''` is to convert it to a string - it allows replace to work.

It's not the same if the text of size changed to include a .

```
"sizcache." + (Math.random() + '').replace('.', '') != ("sizcache." + Math.random() + '').replace('.', '')
```

for example.

Comment: But wait, 'sizcache' is a string, so the conversion to string should already happen.

Comment: sizcache isn't combined with the random number until after the `.replace` method is called. However, you're right in that your second line of code gives an equivalent result.

Comment: not quite the same. This would be the same: ("sizcache" + Math.random()).replace('.', '') but if the text sizecache changed to say have a . in it then there would be a bug created

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are using " + '' " to convert from a number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a quick way to cast the returned value of `Math.random()` as a character string, so it `replace()` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same thing. In their version, they are getting a random number, converting it to a string by concatenating an empty string to it, removing the dot, then appendign `sizcache`. Your version appends `sizcache` to the random number then removes the dot.

Granted, the end result is the same, but could potentially be different with another string value, say if it contained a dot like `siz.cache`.

Comment: Are you saying that `sizcache` might contain a dot?

Comment: In this case, it *might* not, it's a string literal. However, it *could* in the future be repalced for something with a dot in it, and the code would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method will produce the same result.

The `+ ''` part is used to cast the number to a string. Then the `replace` function is called on that string and the `sizcache` string is prepended.

However, with your method you are first adding that string to the number (and converting the number to a string in the process), then calling `replace` on the entire thing. Since you are just removing dots, the result is the same.